# awk first line not working removing columns

Tags: awk

I'm trying to remove columns beyond number 26 from all lines of a file, using this code:

```
awk '{ FS = ";" ; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i<26) printf $i FS}{print $26}'
```

It is working well in all the lines but for the first one, where it shows 2 more fields (and cuts the last in two).

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you set `FS` on every line, while it should be in a `BEGIN{}` block (or outside as a parameter, like others answers correctly suggest):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i<26) printf $i FS}{print $26}' file
```

In fact, to accomplish your goal it is easier to use `cut`:

```
cut -d';' -f-26 file
       ^    ^^^
       |    all fields up to the 26th
       delimiter
```

#### Example with 4 cols

sample file:

```
$ cat a
1col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6
2col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6
3col1;col2;col3;col4;col5;col6
```

previous code:

```
$ awk '{FS=";"; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i<4) printf $i FS}{print $4}' a

2col1;col2;col3;col4
3col1;col2;col3;col4
```

new code:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i<4) printf $i FS}{print $4}' a
1col1;col2;col3;col4
2col1;col2;col3;col4
3col1;col2;col3;col4
```

with `cut`:

```
$ cut -d';' -f-4 a
1col1;col2;col3;col4
2col1;col2;col3;col4
3col1;col2;col3;col4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -F';' 'NF>26{NF=26}1' OFS=';' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

@fedorqui is right.

But you can also use this to set Field Separator :

```
awk -F";" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if (i<26) printf $i FS}{print $26}' file
```